# Can anyone see what im doing wrong opencv will not decode jpeg from std::string buffer but will save string buffer to jpg file ok

Tags: c++, opencv

Here is my code std::str is the buffer containing the jpeg image data. problem is img is has no value when decoding and throws no exceptions.

```
unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)(&str[0]);// convert std::string str to unsigned char*
            cv::Mat img;
            try
            {
                img = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(1, str.length(), CV_8UC1, p), IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
            }
            catch (cv::Exception& e)
            {
                const char* err_msg = e.what();
                TRACE(L"exception caught: %S", err_msg);
            }
            //save jpeg file image save fine from buffer p
            std::fstream file;
            file.open("image.jpg", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
            file.write((char *)p, str.length());
            file.close();
```

Comment: You *do* realize that `std::string` has a `c_str()`-member function?

Comment: Careful with the tagging. You'll attract extra eyes with the C tag, but not all of those extra eyes are interested in debugging C++ code.

Comment: The code never does anything with `img` ?

Comment: HI Yes I know std::string has a c_str() but even using this I still have the same problem. cv::Mat img receives the information from cv::imdecode but my jpeg stream dosnt seem to be getting decoded from the buffered jpeg stream but it will save fine as a jpeg file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The code I posted was correct and works perfect the fault was in the header information of the jpeg buffer. I had not stripped out the last four characters "\r\n\r\n" from the HTTP GET header response that returned the jpg file data from the server. Seems Opencv is very sensitive where std::fstream didn't seen to be effected by the additional 4 characters this is why I was confused. FYI as the code is working cv::Mat img is doing something it holds the data returned from cv::imdecode(..) which is the decrypted jpg data.